# Open PDF in IE11 on new tab without prompting - mssaveoropenblob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, pdf

We are migrating an ASP.NET MVC application, which had the feature to open PDF in a new tab via FileContentResult.

```
return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/pdf");
```

Now we are migrating this app to React and from from the API (server side), we are sending back the response as below :-

```
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfByteArray);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
```

On the React UI side, we are using the response as below :-

```
postData(POST_API_ENDPOINT, requestData, ((err, data) => {
  if (data.ok) {
     data.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
         if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            return window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(myBlob, "sample.pdf");
         }
         else {
           var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
           return window.open(objectUrl);
          }
        });
      }
  }));
```

Now, i understand that msSaveOrOpenBlob would always prompt the user to "open/save" within IE11. What other options do i have if i need to open the PDF in a different tab without the prompts?

I guess there is another way to do that via the below manner, but again the URL length limits that.

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + base64EncodedPDF);
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does not allow us to open Data URL in new tab (possibly security reason) and there no workaround - faced same issue earlier.

We use msSaveOrOpenBlob - found no alternative.